# How to use SQL to only uniquely store into the variables the values where course_ID is the same before resetting?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm tasked with constructing a query that will return all of the course IDs where there are 0 student enrollments. So far what I have is this:

```
DECLARE @inst_stu_count int
DECLARE @total_stu_count int
DECLARE @results int

set @inst_stu_count = (select COUNT(cm.course_id) from course_main cm join course_users cu on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1 where cu.role = 'P' and cm.course_id LIKE '%SP2014')

set @total_stu_count = (select COUNT(cm.course_id) from course_main cm join course_users cu on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1 where cu.role = 'S' and cm.course_id LIKE '%SP2014')

set @results = @total_stu_count - @inst_stu_count

select course_id from course_main cm
join course_users cu on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
where @results = 0
```

edit: As I was typing this out, I realized my logic is faulty due to the nature of SQL and what I'm trying to do.

At our institution instructors enrolled into Blackboard courses have both their primary account and their student account enrolled. This means that if 3 instructors are enrolled there are already 3 students enrolled for a total of 6 enrollments.

My `@inst_stu_count` is supposed to contain the value for the number of instructors in a course, and then `@total_stu_count` is supposed to contain the value for the number of students in a class. Naturally this count will include however many instructor student accounts are in the course so I take the total and subtract `@inst_stu_count` and if its above 0 then I do not count that course as "empty" or void of any actual student enrollments.

The issue I just noticed while typing this posting is that neither of my sub-select statements will produce the desired results because it's getting the count of EVERY course that matches my `WHERE` criteria.

Is there any way I can use SQL to only uniquely store into the variables the values where the course_ID is the same and then until it changes, reset the value and continue?

Class ABC has 9 records for enrollments. So the query would run 9 times, do the math, and select it below if the `@results = 0`.

Class DEF comes along after, the counts should return to 0 and then you go back through the sub-selects.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: If you don't allow courses to have enrollment before an instructor's been assigned, then treat your 6 "students" as 0 real students, and look for classes that have <= 6 enrollments, which would be your basic answer already.

Comment: Instructors and students are differentiated in the tables by a simple indicator, P for instructor and S for students. So I can't just get an arbitrary count from the roles because I'll get everyone without knowing which results came from which role.

The problem isn't really so much as trying to get one classes enrollment examples, as it is trying to get the results from a load of classes without getting other class counts mixed in. The fact that the instructor count is not static means I have to check for the number somehow from EVERY SP2014 class because I'm not just checking one uniquely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can actually solve this with a single query.  Try this:

```
SELECT cm.course_id
FROM course_main AS cm
    INNER JOIN course_users AS cu ON
        cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
GROUP BY cm.course_id
HAVING SUM(CASE cu.role WHEN 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE cu.role WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause handles all the count-checking.  This assumes that the only two possible `role`s are `S` and `P`, or that anything else is not considered at all.

Comment: Nice, that works perfectly, you're the bomb my friend.